# AudioQueueStart But no voice

Tags: swift, audioqueueservices

```
import Foundation
import AudioToolbox

class AudioPlay {

    //setting buffer num
  static  let knumberBuffers = 3 
    var aqData = AQPlayerState.init()
    //A custom structure for a playback audio queue
     class AQPlayerState {
        var mDataFormat = AudioStreamBasicDescription()
        var mQueue:AudioQueueRef?
        var mBuffers = [AudioQueueBufferRef?].init(repeating: nil, count: AudioPlay.knumberBuffers)
        var mAudioFile:AudioFileID?
        var bufferByteSize = UInt32()
        var mCurrentPacket:Int64?
        var mNumPacketsToRead = UInt32()
        var mPacketDescs:UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioStreamPacketDescription>?
        var mIsRunning = false
    }        

    //playbackAudioQueue callback
   static let HandleOutputBuffer:AudioQueueOutputCallback = { (aqData1, inAQ, inBuffer) in

        var pAqData = (aqData1?.assumingMemoryBound(to: AQPlayerState.self).pointee)!

        guard pAqData.mIsRunning || pAqData.mQueue != nil else{
            print("audioplay is not running exit callback func")
            return
        }
        var numBytesReadFromFile = UInt32()
        var numPackets = pAqData.mNumPacketsToRead

        AudioFileReadPacketData(pAqData.mAudioFile!, false, &numBytesReadFromFile, pAqData.mPacketDescs, pAqData.mCurrentPacket!, &numPackets, inBuffer.pointee.mAudioData)

        if numPackets > 0 {
            inBuffer.pointee.mAudioDataByteSize = numBytesReadFromFile

            AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(pAqData.mQueue!, inBuffer, ((pAqData.mPacketDescs != nil)  ? numPackets : UInt32(0)), pAqData.mPacketDescs)

            pAqData.mCurrentPacket! += Int64(numPackets)
        }else{
            AudioQueueStop(pAqData.mQueue!, false)
            pAqData.mIsRunning = false
        }    
    }    

    //call func to set the property 
    //create new outputqueue
    //start th audioqueue
    func start()  {

        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "123", withExtension: "mp3")!

        let audioFileURL = url as CFURL      

        print(audioFileURL)           

        let result = AudioFileOpenURL(audioFileURL, .readPermission, 0, &aqData.mAudioFile)
        print(result)    

        var dataFormatSize = UInt32(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: aqData.mDataFormat))

      let result1 =  AudioFileGetProperty(aqData.mAudioFile!, kAudioFilePropertyDataFormat,&dataFormatSize, &aqData.mDataFormat)    

        //get file property
        var maxPacketSize = UInt32()            
        var propertySize = UInt32(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: maxPacketSize))            

        let result2 = AudioFileGetProperty(aqData.mAudioFile!, kAudioFilePropertyPacketSizeUpperBound, &propertySize, &maxPacketSize)        

        //calculate and setting buffer size
        DeriveBufferSize(ASBDesc: aqData.mDataFormat, maxPacketSize: maxPacketSize, seconds: 0.5, outBufferSize: &aqData.bufferByteSize, outNumPacketsToRead: &aqData.mNumPacketsToRead)

        //check the format is VBR or CBR
        let isFormatVBR = aqData.mDataFormat.mBytesPerPacket == 0 || aqData.mDataFormat.mFramesPerPacket == 0

        if isFormatVBR {
            aqData.mPacketDescs = UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioStreamPacketDescription>.allocate(capacity: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: AudioStreamPacketDescription()))
        }else{
            aqData.mPacketDescs = nil
        }   

      //create new audio queue
        let result4 =  AudioQueueNewOutput(&aqData.mDataFormat,AudioPlay.HandleOutputBuffer, &aqData,CFRunLoopGetCurrent(),CFRunLoopMode.commonModes.rawValue, 0, &aqData.mQueue)      

        //queue start
        aqData.mIsRunning = true

        //alloc memory buffer
        aqData.mCurrentPacket = 0

        for i in 0..<AudioPlay.knumberBuffers {
            AudioQueueAllocateBuffer(aqData.mQueue!, aqData.bufferByteSize,&aqData.mBuffers[i])
            AudioPlay.HandleOutputBuffer(&aqData,aqData.mQueue!, (aqData.mBuffers[i])!)
        }

        //start audioqueue
        AudioQueueStart(aqData.mQueue!, nil)            

        repeat{
            CFRunLoopRunInMode(CFRunLoopMode.defaultMode, 0.25, false)
        }while (aqData.mIsRunning)

        CFRunLoopRunInMode(CFRunLoopMode.defaultMode, 1, false)          
    }       

    //calculate and setting buffer size
    func DeriveBufferSize(ASBDesc:AudioStreamBasicDescription,maxPacketSize:UInt32,seconds:Float64,outBufferSize:UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>,outNumPacketsToRead:UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>) {
        let maxBufferSize:UInt32 = 0x50000
        let minBufferSIze:UInt32 = 0x4000

        if ASBDesc.mFramesPerPacket != 0 {
            let numPacketsForTime = ASBDesc.mSampleRate / Float64(ASBDesc.mFramesPerPacket) * seconds
            outBufferSize.pointee = UInt32(numPacketsForTime) * maxPacketSize
        }else{
            outBufferSize.pointee = (maxBufferSize > maxPacketSize) ? maxBufferSize:maxPacketSize
        }

        if outBufferSize.pointee > maxBufferSize && outBufferSize.pointee > maxPacketSize {
            outBufferSize.pointee = maxBufferSize
        }else{
            if outBufferSize.pointee < minBufferSIze{
                outBufferSize.pointee = minBufferSIze
            }
        }
        outNumPacketsToRead.pointee = outBufferSize.pointee/maxPacketSize
    }    

    //dispose the audioqueue
    func Dispose()  {
        AudioQueueDispose(aqData.mQueue!, true)
        AudioFileClose(aqData.mAudioFile!)
        free(aqData.mPacketDescs)
    }        
}
```

above code is writed according AudioQueueServiceProgrammingGuide!

create an instence of this class,and call the start() func
compile ok,but no output voice.
I had check the code many times but no advancing

can any one who familiar with audiiqueue help me?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace "AudioFileReadPacketData" with "AudioFileReadPackets" can fix this problem!

but I get a new problem like below sometime! sometimes it works well!

Stream Audio(20535,0x1085ac3c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x6080001f6300: Invalid pointer dequeued from free list
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to